# RxJS - Observable Modules - throw undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to throw an error within an observable with the simple bit of code:

```
return Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.throw(new Error('Test'));
});
```

Yet for some reason, `throw` is undefined. I have no idea why at the top of my class, I have the following import:

```
import 'rxjs/observable/throw';
```

I have also tried:

```
import 'rxjs/Observable/throw';
```

and:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Yet none are working? Am I missing a trick?

I am using rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 combined with angular@2.0.0-rc.4 for Ionic 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observers (which have been renamed "Subscribers" in RxJS v5, FYI) don't have a method called `throw()`. You're mixing up Observables (which define sequence and operators on those sequences), and Subscribers/Observers (which just receive next/error/complete messages from an Observable).

What you want is an Observable that just emits an error object. Then, any Subscriber/Observer subscribing to it will get an `.error()` notification. So, instead of using `Observable.create()`, use `Observable.throw(new Error('Test'))`.

This method is also more robust than using `Observable.create(observer => ...)` and calling `observer.error(...)`, because the resulting Observable is guaranteed to uphold the Rx contract. If you were using `.create()`, you have to manually do things like, ensure that no further notifications are emitted after the error, that all subsequent subscribers to the Observable immediately get an error notification, etc. With `Observable.throw(...)`, that's all taken care of for you, automatically.

Comment: This is ace - thanks! The method will be expanded to have functionality that if a condition is satisfied, then it will emit this otherwise an error is thrown (hence the creation of an observable). In that scenario, I'm guessing I should use observer.error(...)?

Comment: If you're already forced to create your Observable 'by hand' using `Observable.create()`, then that might be the best way. Otherwise, I'd `.switchMap()` the source Observable. In the map function, if the source item is OK, then return `Observable.of(item)`; if the item is erroneous, return `Observable.throw(new Error("an error!"))`.

Comment: Thanks so much - this helps tonnes! I haven't touched observables for a couple of months and it's amazing how fast things have moved along. This really helps.